# Jagged edge image scaling in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I am optimizing my site for these higher resolution monitors (especially the new iPad). I have the site formatted the way I want, and I was just increasing the resolution of each image but still constraining it to the DIVs that I currently have. For example, I have an image with a resolution of 483x246 and I have it fitting a DIV with a set size of 188x96.

The images look great on Chrome, Firefox, and most importantly on the new iPad. Even zoomed in it's nice and crisp (as opposed to my old 188x96 image that looked blurry and pixelated when zoomed in).

The problem comes in when I open the page in IE. It displays the image at the correct size but it's jagged. See link to comparison below. I know it's an issue with the way IE resizes and renders pictures on the fly.

My question would be, is there a way to make IE display the picture nicely? If not, is there a way I can put in the code so that if it detects IE, it displays my old low res image? I've looked everywhere but haven't found anything that relates to my specific problem. I know this is a small example but my bigger images do the same thing and are more noticeable. I hope you all can help. Thanks. :)

Comment: Have you considered using smaller images to support the smaller resolutions? Even though the image is displayed smaller, the browser is still downloading the full image, and is using more bandwidth than necessary. This might be a concern especially for mobile users.